# How to rank records using values from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails.

Have this problem. I have two models **customers** and **orders**. **customer** has_many **orders**, and **orders** belongs_to **customer**. Each order has a money value: **cost**.

Now how can i rank the customers by the total **cost** spent on all of his/her orders ?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: In theory, this can be done in SQL: for each `Customer` you fetch a sum on certain field in associated orders and order by that field. But it will be slow, that's for sure. Have you considered caching total `Order` cost **inside** `Customer` model and ordering by cached values?

Comment: `Customer.joins(:orders).order('orders.cost desc')`

Comment: hi. juanpastas. it seems Customer.joins(:orders).order('orders.cost desc')  only rank the customers by their largest order, not the sum of all of their orders :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below

```
Customer.joins(:orders).select('customers.id, sum(orders.cost) as total_order_cost').order("total_order_cost")
```

use `order("total_order_cost desc")` if you want it in descending order

Comment: Thank you ! This helped a lot. Btw, to return multiple records, I have to add `.group("customers.id")` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use grouping to total the orders for each customer. You can then order by the totals.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group has an example that is similar to what you are doing.